# Identical steps while running emcee in parallel with Pool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, emcee

I am running an MCMC process in Python using `emcee`. My python code is a wrapper around a different software. `emcee` walkers sample the input parameter space to this software. The software reads a text file as its input. My code generates this text file using each step of the `emcee` chain. To speed up the sampling, I want multiple processes that evaluate the log-likelihood, running in parallel. However, each of these processes need to write to different input text files, to prevent interference between the processes. For this reason I think I cannot use the simple standard example on the emcee [website](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/parallel/#multiprocessing).

Ideally, I would want each process running in its own subdirectory, generating different input files so that the different processes do not interfere with each other. To do this, I use `Pool` from `multiprocessing` to create parallel processes manually rather than the default option from `emcee`. I understand that in order to make different parallel processes generate different random numbers, I need to supply different seeds to each PRNG. My current code is as follows :

```
def log_likelihood(x):
    #update input text file and run software
    return log_likelihood

def run_mcmc(inp_directory)
    os.chdir(inp_directory)
    seedint = int(dusty_inpdir.split('_')[-1]) #sets a different seed for each process
    np.random.seed(seedint)
    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_likelihood)
    sampler.run_mcmc(initial_pos,ntrials)

pool = Pool()
inp_dirlist = ['proc_0','proc_1','proc_2','proc_3']
pool.map(run_mcmc,inp_dirlist)
```

In spite of giving different seeds to each process, all 4 processes generate exactly the same set of `emcee` steps.

Is `np.random.seed` not the relevant parameter to seed the `emcee` PRNG? Is there a better way to have different processes working in different directories?

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.random.seed` sets the global state of the numpy random number generator. To get each emcee sampler to have a different seed, you should use the `seed` argument:

```
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_likelihood, seed=seedint)
```